# Sorting within groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a student table on sql server 2008 with following columns:

```
StudentID   name    SubjectID   lastUpdatedDate
-------------------------------------------------------
100         abc     01          2013-03-12 04:59:06.430
110         bbc     01          2013-03-12 03:59:06.430
120         cbc     02          2013-03-12 04:58:08.320
130         dbc     03          2013-03-12 02:58:11.320
140         ebc     02          2013-03-12 04:59:06.430
```

The SubjectID refers to a Subject Lookup table:

```
SubjectID | SubjectDescription......
```

I want to list out the last modified student record of each subject type.
The last modified record is determined by descending order on `lastUpdatedDate`.

So - the outcome of the above data should be :

```
100     abc     01  2013-03-12 04:59:06.430
130     dbc     03  2013-03-12 02:58:11.320
140     ebc     02  2013-03-12 04:59:06.430
```

Is there a way this without creating temporary tables?

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get latest update date for each `SubjectID` and then filter result from the original table with `INNER JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tbl t1
JOIN ( SELECT SubjectID
            , MAX(lastUpdatedDate) AS lastUpdatedDate
       FROM tbl 
       GROUP BY SubjectID ) t2 ON t1.SubjectID =  t2.SubjectID
                              AND t1.lastUpdatedDate =  t2.lastUpdatedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select StudentId, name, SubjectId, lastUpdateDate
from (select *
        , row_number() over (partition by StudentId 
             order by lastUpdate desc) as RN
     from Students) S
where RN = 1
```

Will often see better performance using windowed functions than the equivalent query that uses aggregate and self join.

Note, in the case of ties for lastUpdateDate, one is chosen arbitrarily. If you would like all rows that tie for a win, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.